# How to make sure SMS is sent in Android

Tags: android

In my application there will be a notification sms send upon an action. Now how do I make sure that the SMS will be sent?

For example, if there is no network or sim card removeed, how do I ensure that the sms will be sent once there is a network available at a later time? Is it possible to add the sms to the queue?

Is this possible?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the SMS sent/deliver status with a broadcast receiver. The `BroadcastReceiver` must be registered before you send the SMS. I use this implementation, along with a parent class, to get the result of the operation up to the `SENT` or `DELIVERED` status (must chose one of the two)

```
package com.mycie.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

extern class Sequencer;
extern class Test;
extern class Status;

/**
 * Sends multipart SMS to multiple destinations and verifies the send and
 * deliver status of each part sent away. The operation is a success if all the
 * codes of the SMS_SENT of all the messages sent are equal to
 * {@link Activity#RESULT_OK}.
 */
public class SendSms extends ModemDependentAtom {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SendSms";

    // set this flag to true to print many traces to follow the machine state.
    // NB: DEBUG level traces are always printed for the SEND and DELIVER status
    // of the part, so you don't need to activate this flag to get them.
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public static final String SMS_DELIVERY = "com.mycie.myapp.SMS_DELIVERY";

    public static final String SMS_SENT = "com.mycie.myapp.SMS_SENT";

    // infinite time-out
    public static final int TIMEOUT_INFINITE = -1;

    // timeout per part.
    private static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 10000;

    private String mSmsNumber;

    private String mSmsBody;

    private int mTimeout;

    private long mOrgRealtime;

    private SendSmsReceiver mSendReceiver;

    private SendSmsReceiver mDeliverReceiver;

    private int mNbParts;

    private int mDestIndex;

    private int mState;

    private String[] mNumbers;

    private ArrayList<String> mParts;

    private Status mStatus;

    public enum SmsSendNotification {
        SEND,
        DELIVER
    }

    private final SmsSendNotification mSignificantNotification;

    private ArrayList<PendingIntent> mSentIntents;

    private ArrayList<PendingIntent> mDeliveryIntents;

    public SendSms(SmsSendNotification significant) {
        mSignificantNotification = significant;

        mSmsNumber = "";
        mSmsBody = "";
        mTimeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        mOrgRealtime = 0;
        mStatus = Status.NotDone;
        mState = 0;

        mSentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        mDeliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    }

    private final class SendCallBack implements SendSmsReceiver.Callback {

        SendCallBack(Sequencer sequencer, Test test) {
            mSequencer = sequencer;
            mTest = test;
        }

        private Sequencer mSequencer;
        private Test mTest;

        @Override
        public void onPartResult(int part, int code) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("SEND part %d: %s", part,
                    SendSmsReceiver.getCodeString(code)));

            Context context = Controller.controller.getApplication().getApplicationContext();

            if (mSendReceiver.findCode(SendSmsReceiver.RESULT_UNDEFINED) == -1) {
                // no more sent notification to receive.
                int globalCode = mSendReceiver.findNotCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

                if (globalCode == -1) {
                    // all part were sent successfully.
                    globalCode = Activity.RESULT_OK;
                } else {
                    // at least one part failed to be sent.
                    mSequencer.onTestEvent(mTest, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.TEST_EXCEPTION,
                            "one or more parts failed to be sent"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                    mTest.setStatus(Status.Error);
                    mStatus = Status.Executed;
                }

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SMS send result: " + SendSmsReceiver.getCodeString(globalCode));

                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "SEND: " + SendSmsReceiver.getCodeString(globalCode),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    private final class DeliverCallBack implements SendSmsReceiver.Callback {

        DeliverCallBack(Sequencer sequencer, Test test) {
            mSequencer = sequencer;
            mTest = test;
        }

        private Sequencer mSequencer;
        private Test mTest;

        @Override
        public void onPartResult(int part, int code) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("DELIVER part %d: %s", part,
                    SendSmsReceiver.getCodeString(code)));

            if (mDeliverReceiver.findCode(SendSmsReceiver.RESULT_UNDEFINED) == -1) {
                // no more delivery notification to receive.
                int globalCode = mDeliverReceiver.findNotCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

                if (globalCode == -1) {
                    // all part were sent successfully.
                    globalCode = Activity.RESULT_OK;
                } else {
                    // at least one part failed to be sent.
                    mSequencer.onTestEvent(mTest, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.TEST_EXCEPTION,
                            "one or more parts failed to be delivered"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                    mTest.setStatus(Status.Error);
                    mStatus = Status.Executed;
                }

                Context context = Controller.controller.getApplication().getApplicationContext();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SMS deliver result: " + SendSmsReceiver.getCodeString(globalCode));

                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "DELIVER: " + SendSmsReceiver.getCodeString(globalCode),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // we can early examine the send results so do it.
                examine(mSequencer, mTest);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Status process(Sequencer sequencer, Test test) {

        if (mState == 0) {

            mNumbers = PhoneUtils.splitNumbers(mSmsNumber);

            PhoneUtils.parsePhoneNumbers(mNumbers, new PhoneUtils.PrivilegiateSms());

            AppData data = Controller.controller.getData();
            SmsManager smsManager = data.services.getSmsManager();
            mParts = smsManager.divideMessage(mSmsBody);
            mNbParts = mParts.size();

            Context context = Controller.controller.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
            mSendReceiver = SendSmsReceiver.getInstance(context,
                    sequencer.getPosition(), SMS_SENT, new SendCallBack(sequencer, test));
            mDeliverReceiver = SendSmsReceiver.getInstance(context,
                    sequencer.getPosition(), SMS_DELIVERY, new DeliverCallBack(sequencer, test));

            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "broadcast receivers created.");
            }

            mDestIndex = 0;
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "state=1");
            }
            mState = 1;

            process(sequencer, test);

            mStatus = Status.Active;

        } else if (mState == 1) {

            if (mDestIndex < mNumbers.length) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Sending SMS to " + mNumbers[mDestIndex] + "...");
                Status result = sendMultipartText(sequencer, test, mNumbers[mDestIndex]);
                if (result == Status.Error) {
                    // error: fail to send to a receiver.
                    test.setStatus(Status.Error);

                    mStatus = Status.Executed;
                } else {
                    if (DEBUG) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "state=2");
                    }
                    mState = 2;
                }
            } else {
                // no more: completed.
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No more recipient. Test OK.");
                }

                mStatus = Status.Executed;
            }

        } else if (mState == 2) {
            if (mModemReset) {

                sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.EXTERNAL_ERROR,
                        "the test probably caused a modem reset"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                test.setStatus(Status.Error);
                mStatus = Status.Error;

                mModemReset = false;
            }
            // wait for status to change. Force examination if timeout expires.
            else if (isTimerExpired()) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "timeout");
                }
                examine(sequencer, test);
            }
        } else {
            // what?
        }

        if (mStatus != Status.Active) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "status = " + mStatus);
            }
        } else {
            sequencer.wakeAfter(0);
        }

        return mStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinalRelease(Status unused) {
        super.onFinalRelease(unused);

        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "broadcast receivers released.");
        }

        cancelPendingIntents();

        if (mSendReceiver != null) {
            mSendReceiver.discard();
            mSendReceiver = null;
        }

        if (mDeliverReceiver != null) {
            mDeliverReceiver.discard();
            mDeliverReceiver = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        super.reset();

        mState = 0;
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "state=0");
        }

        mStatus = Status.NotDone;
    }

    public void examine(Sequencer sequencer, Test test) {

        // If a SENT result is missing then the test failed due to timeout. The
        // method should have been called by the timeout handler, if not this is
        // a programming error.
        if (mSendReceiver.findCode(SendSmsReceiver.RESULT_UNDEFINED) != -1) {

            sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.TEST_EXCEPTION,
                    "not all send results received before timeout"); //$NON-NLS-1$

            test.setStatus(Status.Error);
            mStatus = Status.Executed;
        }

        // If one or more SENT failed then the test failed.
        else if (mSendReceiver.findNotCode(Activity.RESULT_OK) != -1) {

            sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.TEST_EXCEPTION,
                    "failed to send at least one SMS part."); //$NON-NLS-1$

            test.setStatus(Status.Error);
            mStatus = Status.Executed;
        }

        // Otherwise, if DELIVER is the significant notification then the
        // test fails if there is one or more delivery failed.
        else if (mSignificantNotification.equals(SmsSendNotification.DELIVER)) {
            if (mDeliverReceiver.findCode(SendSmsReceiver.RESULT_UNDEFINED) != -1) {

                // failed due to timeout on DELIVERY
                sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.TEST_EXCEPTION,
                        "not all delivery results received before timeout"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                test.setStatus(Status.Error);
                mStatus = Status.Executed;

            } else if (mDeliverReceiver.findNotCode(Activity.RESULT_OK) != -1) {

                // at least on part delivery failed.
                sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.TEST_EXCEPTION,
                        "failed to deliver at least one SMS part."); //$NON-NLS-1$

                test.setStatus(Status.Error);
                mStatus = Status.Executed;

            } else {
                // OK, proceed with next number.
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "send to next recipient, if any.");
                }
                mDestIndex ++;
                mState = 1;
            }
        } else {
            // SEND is significant and all SENT were OK: proceed with next number.
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "send to next receiver, if any.");
            }
            mDestIndex ++;
            mState = 1;
        }
    }

    private Status sendMultipartText(Sequencer sequencer, Test test,
            String number) {

        Intent sent;
        Intent delivery;
        PendingIntent sentIntent;
        PendingIntent deliveryIntent;

        AppData data = Controller.controller.getData();
        SmsManager smsManager = data.services.getSmsManager();
        Context context = Controller.controller.getApplication().getApplicationContext();

        if (mNbParts > 1) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("SMS is devided in %d parts.", mNbParts));
        }

        cancelPendingIntents();

        String serial = getNewSerial(number);

        int iPart;
        for (iPart = 0; iPart < mNbParts; iPart++) {
            Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(String.format("pos%d", sequencer.getPosition()))
                .authority(serial)
                .appendQueryParameter("part", Integer.toString(iPart))
                .build();
            sent = new Intent(SMS_SENT, uri);

            sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sent, 0);
            if (sentIntent == null) {
                sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.PROGRAM_ERROR, 
                        "null " + SMS_SENT + " intent"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                return Status.Error;
            }

            mSentIntents.add(sentIntent);

            delivery = new Intent(SMS_DELIVERY, uri);

            deliveryIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, delivery, 0);
            if (deliveryIntent == null) {
                sequencer.onTestEvent(test, Level.SEVERE, Sequencer.PROGRAM_ERROR, 
                        "null " + SMS_DELIVERY + " intent");
                return Status.Error;
            }

            mDeliveryIntents.add(deliveryIntent);
        }

        this.mOrgRealtime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "timeout: " + getRealTimeout());
        }

        mSendReceiver.restart(serial, mNbParts);
        mDeliverReceiver.restart(serial, mNbParts);

        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null,
                mParts, mSentIntents, mDeliveryIntents);

        return Status.Executed;
    }

    private static String getNewSerial(String number) {
        String serial = number + "." + SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        return serial;
    }

    private void cancelPendingIntents() {
        // cancel precedent pending intents.
        for (PendingIntent pi : mSentIntents) {
            pi.cancel();
        }
        mSentIntents.clear();

        for (PendingIntent pi : mDeliveryIntents) {
            pi.cancel();
        }
        mDeliveryIntents.clear();
    }

    private boolean isTimerExpired() {
        boolean expired = false;

        long timeout = getRealTimeout();
        if (timeout > 0) {
            if (mOrgRealtime <= 0) {
                mOrgRealtime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            } else {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mOrgRealtime;
                if (elapsed > timeout) {
                    expired = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return expired;
    }

    private long getRealTimeout() {
        long timeout;

        if (mTimeout > 0) {
            if (mSignificantNotification.equals(SmsSendNotification.SEND)) {
                timeout = mTimeout * mNbParts;
            } else {
                // double the times if DELIVER is the significant status.
                timeout = 2 * mTimeout * mNbParts;
            }
        } else {
            timeout = TIMEOUT_INFINITE;
        }

        return timeout;
    }

    public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        mTimeout = timeout;
    }

    public void setNumber(final String number) {
        mSmsNumber = PhoneUtils.normalizeList(number);
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return mSmsNumber;
    }

    public void setBody(final String body) {
        mSmsBody = body;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return mSmsBody;
    }

    /**
     * Send a text message to one or many receivers and forget about the
     * notifications.
     * @param number receiver(s) number(s), separated by a comma if more than one.
     * @param text to send
     */
    public static void sendMessage(String number, String text) {
        AppData data = Controller.controller.getData();
        SmsManager smsManager = data.services.getSmsManager();

        ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(text);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("sending SMS composed of %d parts.", parts.size())); //$NON-NLS-1$

        String[] array = PhoneUtils.splitNumbers(number);
        for (String n : array) {
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(n, null, parts, null, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

please look into the SMS Manager class in android. the link is:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

There is a constant "STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT" . Check the value for this constant to check if the SMS is send.

Answer (score 1):

For the mentioned problem, please see **[Notify if a message you sent was sent successfully or not in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439820/notify-if-a-message-you-sent-was-sent-successfully-or-not-in-android)**  and see the answer of Rupesh Yadav.. It uses the pendingIntent and BroadcastReceiver to note if a message is succesfully sent or not with a simple SWITCH condition.. It worked for me ..