# android sending mms and receiving callback

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi i am trying to send mms using android messaging app and i want to know whether is there any methods as soon the user clicks send button then i should get a callback(means any listener) so that i can return back to my activity and how to know whether mms is send or not this is the code i have used for sending mms

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

       sendIntent.putExtra("address", "895877"); 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");

    Uri.parse("mms://"); 
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "er.png"));


    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    sendIntent.setType("image/png"); 
    startActivityForResult(sendIntent,requestCode);
```

any suggestions will be a great help

Comment: Refer this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695773/how-to-make-sure-sms-is-sent-in-android/9695802#9695802][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695773/how-to-make-sure-sms-is-sent-in-android/9695802#9695802

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

[Detecting MMS messages on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329819/detecting-mms-messages-on-android)

Also note that mms is not part of the standard SDK/API right now, so you might have to do some tinkering to get that to work.