# Notify if a message you sent was sent successfully or not in Android

Tags: android

I have some code here to send a message:

```
SmsManager sms = new SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("911", null, "HALP!", PendingIntent, null);
```

Developer.android says this about `PendingIntent`:

> if not `NULL` this `PendingIntent` is broadcast when the message is successfully sent, or failed. The result code will be `Activity.RESULT_OK` for success, or one of these errors:
>
> `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE`
>
> `RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF`
>
> `RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU`
>
> For `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE` the `sentIntent` may include the extra "errorCode" containing a radio technology specific value, generally only useful for troubleshooting.
>
> The per-application based SMS control checks `sentIntent`. If `sentIntent` is `NULL` the caller will be checked against all unknown applications, which cause smaller number of SMS to be sent in checking period.

My Question is: How can I make a `PendingIntent` to feed into the `sendTextMessage` that simply shows a `Toast` saying either the message was sent or not?

Thank you.